# Space between Y axis and bar on gnuplot histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have gnuplot script like this:

```
set term pos eps
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1
set grid y
set boxwidth 0.8 absolute
set style fill transparent solid 0.8 noborder
#set key outside right top vertical Left

#component stuff
set output 'eps/component.eps'
set title "Component in interesting Issues"
set xlabel "Components"
set xtics nomirror rotate by -270
plot 'dat/!component' using 2:xtic(1) t "Count" lc rgbcolor "blue" lt 1
```

and data:

```
Cmp count
AM    167
NM    90
RM    83
JT    53
TT    51
RED   32
MAP   29
COMM  3
SX    6
HS    68
```

and this is my output:

[image: output]

I see my graph has long spaces between the Y axis and the first bar. How can I spread the bars out evenly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnuplot` gets confused by the first line in your data file, which is supposed to be the header. Just skip this line with `every ::1` and the autoscaling is fine:

```
plot 'dat/!component' using 2:xtic(1) every ::1 t "Count" lc rgbcolor "blue" lt 1
```

Result with 4.6.4:

[image]

In general you don't need to use histograms for this kind of data, the plotting style `with boxes` also works fine.